# Cache control meta tags

Tags: html, meta-tags

I am trying to use cache-control meta tags to avoid browser from caching my files. I have doubt regarding the scope of the meta tags. does the tags apply to every resource request in my html or just my index.html? And also will that apply to XHR request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the tags apply to every resource request in my html or just my index.html?

Just the HTML document itself, in theory, if even that.

[HTML 5 does not mention](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) any cache control headers for its list of defined http-equiv values.

The [extensions wiki](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) has this to say about `cache`:

> **This doesn't actually work**; use HTTP headers instead.

---

> And also will that apply to XHR request?

No.

---

From [mnot](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META):

> Meta tags are easy to use, but aren’t very effective. That’s because they’re only honored by a few browser caches, not proxy caches (which almost never read the HTML in the document). While it may be tempting to put a Pragma: no-cache meta tag into a Web page, it won’t necessarily cause it to be kept fresh.

Use real HTTP headers. It is clear what they apply to (that specific request) and they are much better supported.

Comment: Hey @quentin thanks for the quick reply. will using 'appcache'  work for my case?

Comment: @balajisoundar — I don't know the ins and outs of it too well, but I wouldn't expect so. Use HTTP headers.

Comment: What HTTP headers are being talked about here? There is no further information as to how they can be used to solve this problem. I have a home page update that I'd like to automatically be refreshed by any Chrome user who visits the URL and instead gets a cached version of the old site.

Comment: @addMitt — It's a really broad topic. `Cache-Control` is probably what you want to use. The mnot link goes into a lot of detail.